# Model view controller, what does each word represent

Tags: model-view-controller

I have searched for that answer but it was look like everyone got a different understanding of that:(in comparison to 3 Layer/3 tier)

> "
>
> Model - business logic
>
> View - presentation logic
>
> Controller - changing state of model and view (based on use input)
>
> "

Other wrote:

> " views = frontend ( presentation logic )
>
> models = backend ( Data Access Layer? )
>
> controllers = glue between frontend and backend ( middle tier?
> business logic )  "

If i understand right then:

model- Is the business logic layer?

view- Is the presentation tier\layer?

controllers- ?

Comment: MVC is a _pattern_ - it applies to different levels of abstraction.

Comment: Which one is the right direction abstraction? I know that it depends on the situation but in general? i cant compare to 3-layer(cause its linear?)?

Comment: You contradict yourself. If it depends on the situation, it can't be "general".

Answer (score 2):

**View** = Output and Output Logic only

**Model** = Data anything data related should be coming from a Model

**Controller** = The thing that connects the View and the Model and can do application logic

Business Logic = Further business logic, normally packaged into classes.

User says give me acme.com/home
Controller says, do I know what do do with /home oh yes I have a homeController
homeController says hey I'll go get some stuff from the model or call some business logic from the classes then put it somewhere that the view can access it (viewbag) this bit is sometimes called applicationLogic
homeController then says ok I've done all that now I'll most likely give you a view
View says hello there, and can output anything from the viewbag the controller just prepared for us

Remember the Controller controls everything, the view talks to nothing, here is a simple correct diagram, many diagrams are different and you could say its open to interpretation, but diagrams where the view talk to the model are just not MVC imo.

MVC [image: A simple MVC Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not as plain as it looks as MVC means different things in different contexts.

**Classic MVC (Smalltalk, C++, Java)**

[image: Classic MVC]

- Model contains Data
- View shows Data
- Controller updates Data and processes user interaction

**MVC in Web Applications**

[image: MVC in Web Applications]

- View is the rendered HTML
- Controller is the renderer / request processor
- Model holds data and is used by renderer / request processor

**MVC in ASP.Net MVC**

[image: MVC in ASP.Net MVC]

- View is the rendered HTML
- The ASP.Net stack and the MVC stack handle the requests and rendering
- ASP.Net MVC View are the rendering instructions for rendering the HTML
- ASP.Net MVC Controller is the software component that receives the request from the stack and produces a rendered HTML page using the ASP.Net MVC View.
- Model holds the data and is used by the ASP.Net MVC Controller (which is also responsible for its creation, e.g. by using a service or the entity framework) and the ASP.Net MVC View.

For a complete view of the MVC (3) pipeline see [this document](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http://www.simple-talk.com/content/file.ashx?file=6068&ei=92HtUKvNMsbGtAbIg4H4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHeK8ZRa6raRBaPw4tL7qYvtEpVfg&sig2=mBcKaJ4XaaU6bd6FkvNFfQ&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.Yms).

Answer (score 0):

I tend to look at it as follows:

Model: Blueprint, mostly it is my object class

View: How the user will see it, how I present it

Controller: Any calculations, alterations, ... that need to be done. It serves as a step in between View and Model. It manipulates the data.

Comment: So where are the database calls?

Comment: In my approach I would put them in the "Controller", since you will be modifying data and thus the controller is activated. My "Model" is merely used to store the data once it has been received. This data is not modified in the "Model" itself but in the "Controller" only. It can however be accessed by the "View" but only to read the data, not to modify it.

Comment: So one way to look at it is: view-> front end, model-> the business logic that takes action from the front-end, controller-> the data manipulation, data base call. But here in mvc the controller send it back directly to front-end, I got it right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that one more opinion is going to help, since you sound like you're already confused.

But I think that MVC is actually an *old* concept, going back to Smalltalk days, that needs some revision.

The more modern approach would be to think in terms of layers:

```
View --> Controller --> Service --> Persistence
```

The `View` layer is the HTML or mobile view pages that are displayed to end users.

`Controllers` are tightly coupled to the `View`.  If you change the `View`, it's likely that you'll have to change the `Controller`, too.  It's responsible for listening for requests from the `View`, validating and binding input parameters, passing them to `Services` to fulfill the use case, determining the appropriate next `View`, and serializing the response back to the end user.

The `Service` maps to use cases and fulfills units of work.  It's responsible for transactions.  It's independent of `View`; it's likely to stick around even if `Views` change.  It's the basis for a service-oriented architecture.  It should begin life as an interface, which allows you to deploy it using any technology you prefer: EJB, SOAP or REST web service, XML-RPC, etc.

`Persistence` hides the database from everyone else.  It handles all CRUD operations.

`Model` floats between all the layers.  These are the objects that describe the problem you're solving (e.g. Account, Customer, etc. for banking).

The arrows in the "diagram" are meaningful.  It mimics the package dependencies that objects would have in this arrangement.  `Persistence` doesn't know about `Service`; `Service` doesn't know about `Controller`.

These should be interface-based, so you can change implementations without affecting clients.

Answer (score 0):

They are hierarchically dependent:

Model - Raw Data Model, with object extraction for Controller

Controller - Controls the way the data from the Model is transformed for the View

View - Presentation layer, extracts the data from Controller makes it pretty.

With XML this is:

XML -> XSLT -> HTML